# Two different outputs from Math.round(double * Math.pow(10, int))

Tags: java, android

I am getting a very weird problem. I am getting two different output from the same operation. Problem is described here.

```
double num = 2.0170818E7; 
int dp = 4;

String s = (Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, dp)) / (int) Math.pow(10, dp)) + "";
```

When I am running the above set of code in Android 5.0+ I am getting the output as:

**Correct Output:**

**`20170818`**

When I am running the above set of code below Android 5.0 (I tried with version 4.4.2) I am getting output as:

**Incorrect Output:**

**`20172835`**

The correct output is `20170818` or the expected output. Why I am getting this weird problem?

Comment: Whatever you're actually trying to do in your real code should be done with `DecimalFormat`.

Comment: Implementation of the above code with DecimalFormat would be of great help. @EJP

Comment: To answer that first we would need to now what you're actually trying to do. The code you posted is merely a mathematical identity. It must have had some more overt purpose. What was it?

Comment: @EJP its related to astronomy calculation. I will post the complete code here. I tracked the bug and problem landed in the above equation. All other parts are giving proper answer.

Comment: just curious, are you comparing the same hardware platforms with different os?

Comment: strange you said below 5.0 its not giving expected results but i have tested in jelly bean 4.2 its giving correct output  . . .

Comment: [I don't have an Android environment ready...] Check the value of `Math.pow(10,dp)`. It might be inexact. I'd anyway replace that with a `static final int[] POWERS = {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000 ... }` array of sufficient size and use POWERS[dp] instead of the `Math.pow(10,dp)` computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigDecimal implementation:

```
    double num = 2.0170818E7; 
    int dp = 4;
    BigDecimal pow = new BigDecimal(Math.pow(10, dp));
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(num);
    BigDecimal result = bigDecimal.multiply(pow);
    result = result.divide(pow);
    String s = result.toString();
```

Comment: can you explain your answer in a bit detailed way.

Comment: I'm glad it worked well for you.  BigDecimal class was designed so that arithmetic results would always be exact. BigDecimal is immutable, thus every operation (e.g. multiply(), divide(), etc.) returns a new instance of BigDecimal.

Comment: Link to javadoc:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Answer (score 7):

Originally Android development tools supported only jdk 6 features. But that was changed, first by Android Studio 0.3.2 in October 2013 .Java 7 or higher is required if you are targeting Android 5.0 and higher. Now it is possible to use some features of java 8.

JDK 8 made *intentional* changes to `DecimalFormat` rounding in issue [JDK-7131459: DecimalFormat produces wrong format() results when close to a tie](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7131459).

However, those changes **introduced a real bug** filed as [JDK-8039915: Wrong NumberFormat.format() HALF_UP rounding when last digit exactly at rounding position greater than 5](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8039915).  For example:

```
99.9989 -> 100.00
99.9990 ->  99.99
```

#### Oracle fixed this bug in Java 8 update 40

- [Bug 8039915](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8039915) tracks the OpenJDK [fix for Java 9][JDK9patch]

Comment: Currently i am using java 1.8.111

Comment: I am still facing this problem.

Comment: Yes the problem solved in JDK 8.
I checked this issue on version 4.1.2, 4.3 and 5.1 , all version are giving same output ie. 
                   20170818

Comment: DecimalFormat is used when formatting numbers, not inside calculations. So this can't be the OP's problem. So: interesting info, but off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

[I don't have an Android environment ready, so can't check that on my own...]

Check the value of `Math.pow(10,dp)`. It might be inexact (probably is 9999.999999 or so, looking at the resulting numbers. Casting that to int gives 9999 instead of 10000.

Replace that with a `static final int[] POWERS = {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000 ... }` array of sufficient size and use `POWERS[dp]` instead of the `Math.pow(10,dp)` computation. Then you have exact values.

Or at least divide by the Math.pow() expression directly, not by its int-cast, truncated value.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this "weird" behavior because you're doing floating point arithmetics in Java. Only arithmetics with integers are exact unless you run out of the range of integers. On the other hand floating point arithmetic is not exact since some real numbers require an infinite number of digits to be represented. In Java the moment you start doing real calculation with "double" or "float" (with values outside of the int range) your program will become non deterministic. From one of your comments I understand that you're a physicist so you may be interested in having deterministic calculations and if so you might want to look into using a strictfp library (Java has a strictfp option, I don't know about Android).